# How to replace inner Foreach loops with a Recursive method

Tags: c#, recursion

I'm a bit stuck on creating a method that is generic that can loop through a directed graph to get all possible routes based on max number of depth, for example:

All routes from A with a maximum of 4 hops returns the following concatenated routes:

```
ABCDC  
ABCDE  
ABCEB  
ADCDC  
ADCDE  
ADCEB  
ADEBC  
AEBCD  
AEBCE
```

The routes data is the following Json values:

```
"Routes": [
    {
      "From": "A",
      "To": "B",
      "Distance": 5
    },
    {
      "From": "A",
      "To": "D",
      "Distance": 5
    },
    {
      "From": "A",
      "To": "E",
      "Distance": 7
    },
    {
      "From": "B",
      "To": "C",
      "Distance": 4
    },
    {
      "From": "C",
      "To": "D",
      "Distance": 8
    },
    {
      "From": "C",
      "To": "E",
      "Distance": 2
    },
    {
      "From": "D",
      "To": "C",
      "Distance": 8
    },
    {
      "From": "D",
      "To": "E",
      "Distance": 6
    },
    {
      "From": "E",
      "To": "B",
      "Distance": 3
    }
]
```

And my inner loops, fixed four times is the following, where start would be "A", end would be "C" and the int stops value should determine the amount of recursion, instead of the hard coded loops. Any assistance or guidance in the right direction would be greatly apreciated.

```
public void GetRoutes(string start, string end, int stops)
{
    var tempRoutes = graph.Routes;

    foreach(var route in tempRoutes.Where(x => x.From == start))
    {
        foreach(var innerRoute in tempRoutes.Where(x => x.From == route.To))
        {
            foreach(var innerRoute2 in tempRoutes.Where(x => x.From == innerRoute.To))
            {
                foreach(var innerRoute3 in tempRoutes.Where(x => x.From == innerRoute2.To))
                {
                    totalPath = start + route.To + innerRoute.To + innerRoute2.To + innerRoute3.To;

                    PathCounter.Add(totalPath, totalPath.Length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to write recursive code generally? If not, then Stack Overflow is not really the right place for you to obtain that education; a comprehensive explanation sufficient to answer the question in that context would be far too broad. If you do know how to write recursive code, then please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've tried so far, along with a detailed explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want.

Comment: Note that the basic idea is that you will include in your recursive method a parameter specifying how many more "hops" to traverse. In each recursive call, you'll pass a value that is one less than the value passed to the current call.

Comment: you need an `if-else` that checks for the number of times to do recursive call (`if(stops > 0)`), the number is `int stops`. in each call `stops` must be decremented. inside `if` block put a loop with a call to method itself and inside `else` block put what should be done at last. you probably need to send some more arguments like the queries so you know where you are in each call.

Comment: What does the `string end` parameter supposed to to?

Comment: The start is from where to search, the end is stop. Basically find any values beteen the two. Thanks for suggestions, trying to fix my recursive method as suggested

Comment: you should not be using a **for-each** loop or any loops here.. because you are already working with an `IEnumerable` type..

Comment: @BrettCaswell right. that slow things down. but i think thats higher level of OP's level . he probably have to use `ToList`.

Comment: he doesn't need ToList, unless he's attempting to `Sort` or perform a similar operation.. what he does need to do, is pass in `Func<Route, bool> WhereClause` and `Func<Route, IEnumerable<Route>> SelectCaluse` parameters..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following solution:

The following class models a link between two nodes in the graph:

```
public class NodeLink
{
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
}
```

The following class can search the graph recursively for routes:

```
public class RouteFinder
{
    public IEnumerable<string> FindRoutes(NodeLink[] node_links, string start, string end, int max_length)
    {
        if (max_length == 0)
            yield break;

        if (start == end)
        {
            yield return start;
            yield break;
        }

        if (max_length == 1)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        foreach (var route in node_links.Where(x => x.From == start))
        {
            IEnumerable<string> sub_routes = FindRoutes(node_links, route.To, end, max_length - 1);

            foreach (string sub_route in sub_routes)
            {
                yield return start + sub_route;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
var node_links = new List<NodeLink>
{
    new NodeLink {From = "A", To = "B"},
    new NodeLink {From = "A", To = "C"},
    new NodeLink {From = "C", To = "D"},
    new NodeLink {From = "C", To = "E"},
    new NodeLink {From = "E", To = "F"},
    new NodeLink {From = "B", To = "F"}
};

RouteFinder finder = new RouteFinder();

foreach (string path in finder.FindRoutes(node_links.ToArray(), "A", "F", 4))
{
    Console.WriteLine(path);
}
```

This is the output that I get:

```
ABF
ACEF
```

Comment: you forgot distance property :P

Comment: It is the same as the `max_length` parameter ;)

Comment: @YacoubMassad - Thanks, will give it a try. I can now see where I went wrong by not decrements the max value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final implementation using Recursion.

```
            private List<string> GetRouteMap(string start, int max)
    {
        var startNode = GetNode(start);
        List<string> selectedRoutes = new List<string>();

        //safety check
        if(max == 0)
        {
            selectedRoutes.Add(start.ToString());
            return selectedRoutes;
        }

        Edge[] possibleRoutes = GetRoutes(startNode);
        foreach(Edge edge in possibleRoutes)
        {
            //recursive call until max==0
            List<string> routeMap= GetRouteMap(edge.To.Name, max - 1, exact);

            foreach(string route in routeMap)
            {
                selectedRoutes.Add(startNode.Name + route);
            }
        }

        return selectedRoutes;
    }
```

This returns all possible routes between two nodes with n amount of stops as specified with int max parameter.